# Rolling average Pandas for 3 week period for specific column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe 'qbPast' which contains nfl player data for a season.

```
P   Player  Week    Team    Opp Opp Rank    Points  Def TD  Def INT Def Yds/att Year
2   QB  Kyler Murray    2   ARI MIN 14  38.10   1.8125  1.0000  6.9 2021
3   QB  Lamar Jackson   2   BAL KC  6   37.26   1.6875  0.9375  7   2021
5   QB  Tom Brady   2   TB  ATL 28  30.64   1.9375  0.7500  6.8 2021
```

I am attempting to create a  new rolling average based on the "Points" column for each individual player for each 3 week period, for the first two weeks it should just return the points for that week and after that it should return the average for the 3 week moving period e,g Player A scores 20,30,40,30,40 the average should return 20,30,30,33.3 etc.

My attempt `# qbPast['Avg'] = qbPast.groupby('Player')['Points'].rolling(3).mean().reset_index(drop=True)`

The problem is it is only returning the 3 week average for **all** players I need it to filter by player so that it returns the rolling average for **each** player, the other players should not affect the rolling average.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is index alignment. Don't use `reset_index` instead drop the zeroth index level then assign the values to a column

```
qbPast['Avg'] = qbPast.groupby('Player').rolling(3)['Points'].mean().droplevel(0)
```

Comment: It is also important to sort the dataframe by column 'week' because otherwise the rolling() will take consecutive rows of data which are not consecutive weeks

Comment: Ok thanks quick question does this average include the current week? I'm trying to use it for projections so it shouldn't include the current week but use the 3 previous ones instead? E.g for week 4 it should return the average for the first 3 weeks but not the current one as you shouldn't "know" this at the time

Comment: By default it will include the current week in order to prevent that you can shift the rolling mean: `df.groupby('Player', group_keys=False)['Points'].apply(lambda s: s.rolling(3).mean().shift())`

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the `.reset_index(drop=True)` into `.reset_index(0, drop=True)` so it is not mixing the players indices together.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way of avoiding the index problem is using groupby - transform:

```
qbPast['avg'] = (qbPast.
             sort_values('Week').
             groupby('Player')['Points'].
             transform(lambda g: g.rolling(3).mean()))
```